# Div with image inside css class not showing in IE or Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div with a css class like so:

```css
 .sideArrowImage {
    content:url('https://p41tarste2uscdn.blob.core.windows.net/cfc4678d-f1bd-42d0-93ba-b576ca0efc63/c114d41e-2e9d-4750-bcc6-84c587b7528c/media/images/non-resp%20arrow.png');
      }
```

```html
  <div class="sideArrowImage"></div>
```

The image appears in Opera/Firefox/Chrome. It does not appear in IE11 or Edge. How do i make the image appear in IE11 or Edge?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `content` [property](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_gen_content.asp) is only valid on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, you should use an `<img>` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) or the css `background` [property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

---

```css
.sideArrowImage {
  background:url('https://p41tarste2uscdn.blob.core.windows.net/cfc4678d-f1bd-42d0-93ba-b576ca0efc63/c114d41e-2e9d-4750-bcc6-84c587b7528c/media/images/non-resp%20arrow.png') no-repeat; 
  width:23px;
  height:23px;
 }
```

```html
Img tag:<br>
<img src="https://p41tarste2uscdn.blob.core.windows.net/cfc4678d-f1bd-42d0-93ba-b576ca0efc63/c114d41e-2e9d-4750-bcc6-84c587b7528c/media/images/non-resp%20arrow.png" alt="=>" height="23" width="23">
<br><br>
Background CSS property:<br>
<div class="sideArrowImage"></div>
```

Comment: i tried background and background-image. Neither one worked.